# How to send live, constantly updating data from REST API to mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, rest, mobile, real-time

What's the best way to send constantly updating data from a server (over a REST API or a socket) to an iOS or Android app? Should I create a socket connection and have a socket server that pumps out data, or should I have the app periodically poll a backend resource? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Should I create a socket connection and have a socket server that
>   pumps out data

This is an option. I know some top apps on the play store that use web sockets for streaming data.

> Have the app periodically poll a backend resource

I would recommend against this. Polling drains the battery. The android OS will keep the CPU in idle mode at times and constant polling can wake the CPU up and cause a drain in battery. Users wont like that. You are also wasting processing power when there are no results from the server.

The easiest way to send push notifications / minor updates to the android phone is via GCM. The GCM messages are delivered in near real-time (I noticed a lag of about a second for my apps). The payload is limited to 4k and the messages are stored for up to 4 weeks. This is another option you can consider based on your use case.

Comment: i strongly recommend AGAINST incorporating any google service (like cloud messaging recommended above). as Google changes its user policies, charging for previously free usage being the consolidated business model.  Case in point feb 2012 google maps api is not free anymore and any asset tracking must pay 25 dollars per month per asset (if you tracked 100 people or vehicles, it was now 2500 dollars a month that you owed google.  DO NOT USE GCM EXCEPT IN NONDISTRIBUTABLE APPS

Comment: @tonygil totally disagree. GCM is a well known and widely used service for delivering notifications to Android. Everyone changes user policies, and it is unlikely that they will start charging for GCM

Comment: Until 2012, google maps was free and EVERYBODY used it, including for tracking apps: `https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/`

Answer (score 1):

The typical model I follow is to hit the server on a specified interval and download the updated data.

Answer (score 1):

- Polling is bad, it drains out the battery
- If you want to update the screen when the application is in the foreground, it is better to go with Socket Connection. You can see the changes in realtime.

For this, you need to create a socket server and open a connection between the device and the server.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/3437391-real-time-communication-with-streams-tutorial-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use MQTT protocol to publish and subscribe data. Libraries for iOS(Moscapsule) and Android(Paho) for integrating MQTT protocol are available and can easily be integrated in mobile apps. 
Backend needs to be configured to support MQTT also. Detail information about how MQTT works can be found [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/what-is-mqtt-and-how-it-works/).

Answer (score 0):

I am going to paste my accepted answer from a similar question that was posted a few hours ago.

It can be done using sockets or polling the server but I wouldn't recommend either for a production level app. You will eventually need security features and *as a frontend developer*, it would be difficult to start from scratch.

I would suggest using a third party service. Take a look at [Space Cloud](https://github.com/spaceuptech/space-cloud). It is an open source alternative to Firebase where you can use your own database and has built in security features. If you want to go deeper, it uses [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) for realtime database features.

If those don't suit you then the best option would be to go with GCM.

Answer (score 0):

> should I have the app periodically poll a backend resource?

this must be the last option to put in consideration. as long as the client number increases you need to scale out backend/server and this is not as simple as putting an another server next to existing one.

the perfect solution will be a push oriented design and best approach will be to register clients to events and server will push clients if that specific events occur.

you need to be more specific about your business case. you had mentioned real-time in your question but what kind of real-time is that. is it a video streaming, chat application or just ordinary rest calls?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'll want your server to push updates to the clients because polling is expensive, may not scale well with *N* number of clients, and will drain your phone batteries faster. Depending on your server technology:

**.NET/Core**:
May want to take a look at [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) to push notifications from the backend to your client apps.

**Java**:
May want to take a look at [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) to push notifications from the backend to your client apps.

I have used SignalR with good results publishing to phone clients. Have not used Atmosphere, but it has good reviews.